# How do I use PHP and curl to ping the same way as windows ping

Tags: php, networking, curl

When I use the windows command 'ping', I can ping just the IP address and get a result; even with just the IP address, xxx.xxx.xxx. No port is required for this to work.  I am pinging an IP that has only HTTPS and a non-standard port, yet 'ping still works.

After trying several versions of GET_HEADERS and fsockopen I still can't get a successful return from pinging with PHP.

What I need is to be able to ping an IP address not knowing the port or HTTP protocol and determine if the server is up.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you have access to exec?

Comment: Ping has nothing to do with HTTP or even TCP.  It's part of a special protocol (ICMP). The [`socket_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) has some info to do that (there is even some example `ping()` code in the comments).

Comment: a successful "ping" does not really tell you if a sever is "up". well depending on your definitions. If you want to check if abc.com is available for me to browse, ping is not a good option

Comment: I plan on using 'ping' function to determine if an IP address exists, then if it does I can use curl functions to determine the type of services on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in order to use fsockopen and curl, you need to know the port .Try using a exec command like so.

```
<?php
$ping = exec("ping www.stackoverflow.com");

if ($ping == 0){
   echo "Reached server";
}
else
{
  echo "Failed to reach";
}
?>
```

php.net/exec for more on exec

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It works great.  Do you have any idea about performance vs multi_curl?